# Netty 3.x can`t use openssl?

Tags: openssl, netty

I did not find the class about openssl in netty 3.5.3.Final,and I update the version to 3.10.6,the last version of netty 3,in this jar I found openssl class,but console give me error log,client doesn`t support openssl.

I follow the code,and found this

```
    public static SslContext newClientContext(
        SslProvider provider, SslBufferPool bufPool,
        File certChainFile, TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory,
        Iterable<String> ciphers, Iterable<String> nextProtocols,
        long sessionCacheSize, long sessionTimeout) throws SSLException {

    if (provider != null && provider != SslProvider.JDK) {
        throw new SSLException("client context unsupported for: " + provider);
    }
```

So I must use netty4 to support openssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should use 4.x. Also note that 3.x is EOL for a long time.